# PHP extension conflict with Ioncube extension

Tags: php, php-extension, ioncube

The problem is with the IonCube obfuscation library being used to encode/obfuscate their PHP application. 
This IonCube library which is a zend extension, is interfering with PHP extension.
When IonCube is enabled, for all encoded/obfuscated PHP pages monitored, PHP extensions’ “myextensionfunc” method is being skipped because of which I am having problem in my extension code and some transaction related values are missing. 
“myextensionfunc i.e. (zend_execute)” function is used by my PHP extension to identify the some transaction related values and to monitor php app methods.

Problem here is that - Is there any workaround(apart from disabling ioncube) so that ioncube doesn't interfere with my php extension?

Please provide some thoughts on this, thanks.

Comment: Never seen/hear that. :D I'm using IonCube with no issue.

Comment: @vietanhyt I dont have problem with ioncube , problem is ioncube uses zend_execute func call which my extn also uses , hence it is conflicting. My application uses zend_execute of ioncube rather that calling from my extension